# ¿Cómo crear mi propio localhost en mi aplicación .exe "Python"?

Tags: mysql, python, servidor, localhost, pymysql

Hice una aplicacion de escritorio que conecta a **MySql** con **pymysql** y ejecuta las consultas fino, puedo crear base de datos y puedo crear mis tablas desde **pymysql**, el problema es que estoy trabajandolo local con **Xampp**(mi servidor local), pero cuando convierto mi aplicacion a un "**.exe**" y la pruebo en otra pc me aparece el siguiente error:

> Cant connect to mysql server on 'localhost' | No se puede establecer una conexión ya que el equipo de destino denegó expresamente dicha conexión

Entiendo que el error anterior se deba a que no conecta al servidor local ya que la otra pc ni ninguna otra pc tiene instalado Xampp y ahi radica el problema y mi duda, ¿Como puedo hacer para que desde mi propia aplicacion pueda generar mi servidor local y el servidor mysql correctamente tal como lo hace Xampp... ?

Agradezco sus respuestas de antemano...

PD: No inserto codigo porque no hace falta ya que mi aplicacion desde .py se ejecuta correctamente.

Comment: XAMPP es solo un empaquetador de cosas. En la pc de destino, tenes que instalar mysql y tu programa debe tener las credenciales para conectarse a el. El proceso es un poquito mas complejo de lo que parece, pero se puede hacer...

Comment: Hola! , igual si instalo mysql en la pc de destino, al pasar mi aplicacion a otra pc necesita que instale mysql no?

Comment: XAMPP una de las cosas que instala es mysql, pero no necesitas xampp para instalar mysql... se puede instalar tranquilamente solo, ya que no requiere ningun tipo de servidor web, es solamente un motor de base de datos. Cada vez que pases tu programa a otra pc, necesitarias instalar y configurar mysql. eso lo puede hacer un instalador.

Comment: No hay manera de que me sirva portable?

Comment: @Abdiel Menudo *cacao* mental que tienes. `Portable` no tiene nada que ver con lo que buscas. Lo que tu buscas es una base de datos **embebida**, como, por ejmplo, `SQLite`.

Answer (score 3):

No puedes "crear" un localhost en otra maquina. Es un error de concepto. LOCALHOST es en sí misma la maquina donde ejecutas tu programa. Así que todos somos nuestro propio LOCALHOST. Lo que te ocurre es que dependes de un servidor de MySQL que solo tienes instalado en tu maquina donde has creado tu programa y que además estas diciéndole a tu programa que lo busque en LOCALHOST, es decir, en "ella misma".

El problema viene en que tendrías que instalar un servidor MySQL en todas las maquinas que quieras hacer funcionar tu programa, y eso implica dos consideraciones:

- Tener que instalar individualmente MySQL y configurarlo
- No heredas la información almacenada en la base de datos puesto que cada servidor MySQL tendrá sus propias tablas que no se comparten entre todos tus programas

¿Solución?: Aquí entramos en opiniones y apreciaciones personales que están fuera de las normas de la comunidad pero una manera de evitar ese conflicto es no utilizar MySQL y pasarte a SQLite en un archivo local de tu programa. Depende de tus necesidades quizás sea una opción valida

Comment: Hola ! , muy buena tu respuesta, sigo con mi duda, puedo usar SQLite para mi programa y que me sirva portable?

Comment: SQLite la ventaja que tiene es que únicamente creas un archivo y esa es tu base de datos con las tablas que necesites. "" Pienso "" que la sintaxis SQL es prácticamente la misma y si has utilizado un mapeador de bases de datos (como `peewee`) no te debería costar mucho trabajo pasar de uno a otro. Mientras ese archivo lo inlcuyas en tu paquete no hay problema. Pero sigues teniendo el problema de la localidad de tus datos, cada programa tendrá su propia base de datos y su contenido será único de cada instalación